# Set theory - axiom of powers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading Halmos' Naive Set Theory.

He writes: If $\mathcal C $ is a collection of subsets of a set $ E $ (that is, $\mathcal C $ is a subcollection of power set $ \wp(E) $), then write

$\mathcal  D = \{X \in \wp(E):X^{\complement}\in \mathcal C\} $

If $E = \{1,2\} $ and $\mathcal C = \{\{1\},\{2\}\} $ does $\mathcal C =\mathcal  D $?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is $X'=E\setminus X$?

Comment: I'm not sure it does not mention what X is.

Comment: Does the book mention what the $'$ symbol means?

Comment: Yes... an often used symbol for the temporarily absolute (as opposed to relative) complement of A is A'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "yes".

$\mathcal D=\{X\in\wp(E)\mid X^{\complement}\in\{\{1\},\{2\}\}\}=\{\{1\}^{\complement},\{2\}^{\complement}\}=\{\{2\},\{1\}\}=\mathcal C$

Comment: Thank you! I've asked this question on here before but I've never had an answer

Comment: You are welcome. Check the edit of the question and get familiar with  [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: s see, does the small c denote a compelment of C?

Comment: $A^{\complement}$ denotes the complement of $A$. In your case the set $E-A$.

Comment: There is no A in my example?

Comment: Then let me say: for **every** $A\subseteq E$ the set $A^{\complement}$ denotes the complement of $A$ with respect to $E$ which is the set $E-A$. It does not matter what letter is used here.

Comment: Thanks understood so in my example it's X :)